# How to get rid of these substrings from a string in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have a java string of form "a_x,b_y,c_z".

I would like to get rid of chunk before `_` and after `,` `.`

So I need to get x,y,z.

How can I achieve this?
I am trying to make `String.replaceAll(",*_",",")` work but get error:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0

Please help.

Comment: Learn how regular expressions work. `,*_` is not a valid regular expression. See the API documentation of `java.util.regex.Pattern`.

Comment: How about `String.replaceAll("._","");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works for me:

```
String b = a.replaceAll("[\\w]_", "");
```

It depends on what you need to replace, I'm considering just characters in the class \w, but you can tweak this part to match whatever you like.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty easy. I think this is what @p2pnode needs.

Comment: ab_xx,bc_yy is giving out axx,byy . losing the character just before _

Comment: Like I said... tweak it. My expression is matching any one character that belongs in the \w class before an underscore. If you need one or more, you'd rewrite that rule as "[\\w]+_", if you need 0 or more, use * instead of +.

Comment: Indeed, if what's important is `,` and `_` as separators you could use `"[^_,]*_"` because it tells to replace with "" all what's not an underscore nor a comma before the underscore.

Answer (score 2):

`*` means 0 or more occurences, and by itself doesn't mean anything, it's an error. You have to specify what you want 0 or more occurences of:

```
"a_x,b_y,c_z".replaceAll(",.*_", ",")
```

gives:

```
a_x,y,z
```

or better:

```
"a_x,b_y,c_z".replaceAll(",[^_]*_", ",")
```

where the `[^_]` means any character which isn't `_`.

Comment: "a_x,b_y,c_z".replaceAll(",[^_]*_", ",") works and is neat. But how to get rid of the first _ as well?

Comment: "a_x,b_y,c_z".replaceAll(",[^_]*_", ",").replaceAll("^[^_]*_", "")

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "a_x,b_y,c_z";
for (String split : input.split(","))
{
  String output = split.split("_")[1];
  System.out.println(output);
}
```

The variable `output` changes for every iteration of the loop (from `x` to `y` to `z`).

Comment: The output here would be "x\ny\nz" (where \n is a new line). The variable `output` would change for every iteration of the loop (from "x" to "y" to "z").